# Can Cognito user pool Sign-in through another Cognito user pool?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am working on a project where we are building Authentication system for a coaching center. Our project needs to provide AuthN for students and teachers. A student can register for a class and that'll give that student permission to setup username and password **only** for that class. However, for instructors we want them to be able to Authenticate with same set of credentials for all classes.

The design we were looking into was to create one user pool for Instructors and one User Pool per class. Then allow sign-in through instructor user pool in class user pool. Something like this:

[image]

On checking instructions for setting up [OIDC Provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html) I was able to add `Instructor Cognito User Pool` as OIDC Provider in `CLASS A`. After this I created an AppClient in `CLASS A` and used following format URL to sign in.

```
https://CLASSA-domain/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com
```

When I am signing in with a user in `Instructor Pool` I am getting `The username or password you entered is invalid` error. However, when I try with hosted UI of `Instructor Pool` I am able to sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use case you mentioned is easily solved by using [Cognito user groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html) instead of creating multiple user pools. Create a group for every class and attach the permissions required to that group. For teachers, simple grant them permissions for all the classes.